# Transponse rows to columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, transpose

I got a simple python-made xlsx-sheet with 2 rows.

Something like this:

```
2   , 23   , 124  , 50 ...

3.3 , 3.44 , 2.67 , 7,3 ...
```

Is there a way to transponse it, like I can do in excel?

Since it usually contains between 50-100 values - I need a solution which can transpose it no matter how many entries my rows got.

I already tried everything i found on google. But since I am beginner in python I don't seem to be able to get a working solution by myself.

Comment: "pivot" is the keyword. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067726/pandas-how-to-pivot-one-column-in-rows-into-columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd

# define dataframe, or df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 23, 124, 50],
                   [3.3, 3.44, 2.67, 7]])

# transpose and export to excel
df.T.to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False)
```

Note `pd.DataFrame.T` is shorthand for the [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) method. Result:

```
print(df.T)

       0     1
0    2.0  3.30
1   23.0  3.44
2  124.0  2.67
3   50.0  7.00
```